# Programmatically get CID number of a SD Card android

Tags: android, unique, sd-card

I am trying to get CID number programmatically in my App. I am using the below code:

```
public void getCID() {

    File input = new File("/sys/class/mmc_host/mmc1");
    String cidDirectory = null;

    File[] sid = input.listFiles();

    for (int i = 0; i < sid.length; i++) {
        if (sid[i].toString().contains("mmc1:")) {
            cidDirectory = sid[i].toString();
            String SID = (String) sid[i].toString().subSequence(cidDirectory.length() - 4, cidDirectory.length());
            Log.d("MainActivity", "SID of MMC = " + SID);
        }
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader CID = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cidDirectory + "/cid"));
        String sdCid = CID.readLine();
        mCidNo = sdCid.toString();
        Log.d("RegistrationActivity::", "CID :sdCid.length() = " + sdCid.length());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("RegistrationActivity::", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("RegistrationActivity::", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is the last 2 digits of the CID number is changing from phone to phone. When I decoded the CID number I found that it is checksum. How can I use the CID number as a unique number ? Or can I use any other field as SD Card unique number ?